# TextField clear button

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I have 5 textField popovers that are all dependant on each other. The value in the first field sets what will show in popover for second field and so on...

If the user removes one of the fields, I want to be able to clear all fields following that are linked to this field. I started by using the textFieldShouldClear method, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell it which textField is being cleared. It either clears everything, or doesn't clear at all.

Thanks

Comment: I just need to tell it "if textField is selected or active, to execute code, else, do execute some other code". Im not sure how to transfer that into code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your textFields are set up in IB, which means you can declare 5 IBOutlet UITextField objects in your header file and hook these up to the fields in IB. Then in your delegate method, you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    if([textField isEqual:myField1]) {
        myField2.text=@"";
        myField3.text=@"";
        ...
    }
    else if([textField isEqual:myField2]) {
        myField3.text=@"";
        ...
    }
     //etc....
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps!